Book set in modern times about a girl who can shapeshift into a wyvern and fly
I read a book probably around 10 or more years ago that I can’t remember the name of about a girl who turns into a wyvern. It’s set in modern times. I vaguely remember her sneaking out of her room to change shapeshift into a wyvern and fly? There might also have been other shapeshifters too (for some reason, I’m thinking of a gecko?) but that’s all I can remember!
It’s not the Jennifer Scales series, although I can’t remember if it even is a series or just a standalone book. If anyone can help I’d really appreciate it!!

Could this be Fire & Heist by Sarah Beth Durst?

In Sky Hawkins's family, leading your first heist is a major milestone--even more so than learning to talk, walk, or do long division. It's a chance to gain power and acceptance within your family, and within society. But stealing your first treasure can be complicated, especially when you're a wyvern--a human capable of turning into a dragon.

Early in the book we see her sneaking into her own house to get back to her bedroom.

Anyway, I came home, let myself in, kicked off my shoes, reset the locks and perimeter alarms, and then raided the refrigerator for leftover Chinese food. Taking a container of lo mein, I was walking up the back staircase to my bedroom when I heard the faint tinkle of breaking glass from the front of the house.


For the record, I strongly suspect that the author started with the pun title first, then wrote the novel to fit.

Possibly The Dragon Diaries trilogy by Deborah Cooke, the first of which is Flying Blind from 2011. The main character is Zoe, who is the "Wyvern", the only female dragon shifter. She can (after gaining her powers) turn into a dragon and fly; she's also capable of turning into a salamander (which could be the gecko form you remember?).
Zoe's Dad does ground her at one point, so some sneaking out is required (as she and her friends battle the Mages to stop them killing off the last four races of shifters, dragons, thunderbirds, wolves and cats).
It's not strictly set in modern times, as it's set in a 2024 as imagined from 2011, though close enough (the only real difference seems to be that Smartphones are called "Messengers").
